# TCL: Using sed getting extra characters after close brace

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Trying to write a sed pattern replacement in tcl.

```
sed -i '$a\}\' input
```

i tried following but it reports me an error.

```
sed -i {$a\/} \} input
```

Even i escaped "}" close brace which i need to place at end of input file, this isn't working, any ideas

Comment: Single quotes have absolutely no special meaning in Tcl.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work ok:

```
exec sed -i "\$a\\}\\" input
```

Comment: Please Accept the answer if it solves your problem, thanks.